# Web Service, webservicex currency converter php

Tags: php, converters, currency

I am trying to use the web service for http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL.
I am able to convert the amount when feed in two currencies ie "NZD" "GBP" etc. But i need to have two drop down boxes that get all the currency codes and put them in as options. I don't know how to get these currency codes. Thank You

Code for php is

```
/* Get the values for the amount and currencies */
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$currency1 = $_POST['currency1'];
$currency2 = $_POST['currency2'];

// Set the url for the webservice.
$wsdl="http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL";

// Make soap client.
$client = new SoapClient( $wsdl );

// Set up the parameters
$country=array();

// Set the country variable to the country codes.
$country['FromCurrency']= $currency1;
$country['ToCurrency'] = $currency2;

// Use the client to run the required operation and receive a response
$result = $client->ConversionRate($country);


// Print the results.
print("<br /> The exchange rate from <b>".$country['FromCurrency']."</b> to    <b>".$country['ToCurrency']."</b> is: <b>". $result->ConversionRateResult)."</b><br />";
}
?>
```

In the html i have two select boxes that i need to populate with the country codes ('NZD', 'GBP' etc) which will be currency1 and currency2 variables. I want to get these currency codes from webservicex as an array or something i can use to populate the select boxes.

Comment: share your code so far and do you need country codes or currency codes?

Comment: -1 Not a real question. [**Learn how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://github.com/florianv/swap. It supports multiple providers and will save you the low level stuff.